# Multiple Conditional Statement Execution in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The following statements need to be evaluated if their content is not nil and submitted.  The receiving end does not accept nil values.

```
  :customer => {
    if !@transaction.name.nil? :first_name => @transaction.nome,
    if !@transaction.last_name.nil? :last_name => @transaction.last_name,
    if !@transaction.nation_id.nil? :country_name => @transaction.nation.name
    },
```

Without the condition a simple statement `:first_name => @transaction.nome,` is properly evaluated and the syntax with brackets and commas is proper.  However, the introduction of the condition creates blanks in cases of nil values and generates a **syntax error** `unexpected '}'`.

How can this be overcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the values and later filter them out. Will save you from all those checks:

```
:customer => {
    :first_name => @transaction.nome,
    :last_name => @transaction.last_name,
    :country_name => @transaction.nation.try(:name)
 }.reject{ |_, v| v.nil? }
```

Comment: I believe to have successfully implemented this with a minor variant: take into account empty values  `.reject{ |_, v| (v.nil? || v.empty?) }`.  Hit a different snag on the other end so will delay in fully confirming. I appreciate the conciseness of the approach

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work for the OP's question code. When transaction.nation_id is nil, then transaction.nation won't be found, then transaction.nation.name will raise an exception.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson Makes sense. Used try to see if name can be fetched, returns nil otherwise.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think you want try(:nation) instead of try(:name).

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson No. It should. if `@transaction.nation` is nil, calling `try(:name)` on that will always return `nil`. `@transaction.nation` will never raise an exception; if association doesn't exist, it will only give nil.

Comment: I see it raise an exception. Do you see your code raise an exception when you run it on this input? https://gist.github.com/joelparkerhenderson/ae3e3f34bdc6036abca8

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson Actually, the misunderstanding here is - you are assuming `nation` as one open-struct object which has it's own attributes; and I'm assuming that `customer` has one nation (`nation_id`) association, and thus `@customer.nation` gives nil if not present, else the associated object. I guess OP can ask or infer the workaround for problem like this.

Comment: Yes, right. Currently the OP's question doesn't state whether transaction.nation may raise an exception or not. The example code is an implemenation where the traversal is unsafe. My bias is toward code that is safer on unknowns; yours is toward typical Rails -- and you're probably right! :)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to build the hash:

```
h = {}
if @transaction.name      !=nil then h[:first_name]   = @transaction.name        end
if @transaction.last_name !=nil then h[:last_name]    = @transaction.last_name   end
if @transaction.nation_id !=nil then h[:country_name] = @transaction.nation.name end
:customer => h
```

If you know that your items are always truthy or nil, never falesy, then this is shorter:

```
if @transaction.name      then h[:first_name]   = @transaction.name        end
if @transaction.last_name then h[:last_name]    = @transaction.last_name   end
if @transaction.nation_id then h[:country_name] = @transaction.nation.name end
```

Comment: I guess I miscommunicated something.  The nil element should not generate a hash component.  As it is, I'm passing along a nil value which is not acceptable to the receiver

Comment: The code above does not pass along a nil value. Each line says "Is this value nil? If so, do not add it to hash".

Comment: Trailing conditions are often confusing, especially the sort that lean heavily on the loose-binding `or`.

Comment: @tadman Ok I'll update; what do you like best for the syntax?

Comment: "Surprise conditions" of any sort usually trip people up. What looks like an assignment is actually rendered conditional by the clause at the end, confusing what's actually happening, so whenever possible, just spell it out directly with a leading `if`. In this case a mapping table would reduce the number of `if` statements required. Additionally, comparing `!= nil` is usually pointless unless you're worried about distinguishing between `nil` and `false`, a very uncommon case.

Comment: So you're suggesting "if x then y end", yes? When you suggest a mapping table, how are you suggesting it for the `.nation.name` item? Yes, !=nil is to distiguish nil from false; I agree it's very uncommon yet the OP did use #nil? so I figure I'll match that.

Comment: Seeing `then` is also unusual, though not to get too hung up on all this. I think you can have one `if` and an `each` or `map` call that can clean it up. The answer by @kiddonrails does a great job in this regard.

Comment: The clean-up style can be problematic in a typical Rails app. For example the answer by @kidonrails would try to load a missing association via `nation_id` then try to deference `nation.name`, then raise an exception.

Comment: That has been fixed above :)

Answer (score 1):

You could kill some duplication by adding a small lambda

```
customer: {}.tap { |h|
  conditional_store = -> key, value { h.store(key, value) unless value.nil? }
  conditional_store[:firstName,    @transaction.name]
  conditional_store[:last_name,    @transaction.last_name]
  conditional_store[:country_name, @transaction.nation.name]
}
```

Comment: Would probably be better expressed as a function of some kind rather than an inline lambda, but this is the right idea.

Comment: This code doesn't work for the OP's question because this code doesn't handle the @transaction.nation.name item.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson updated. You could potentially make a case for monkey patching a method onto Hash to do this but this is simple enough

Comment: @tadman are you suggesting the whole value for `customer:` should be wrapped behind a method or the `conditional_store` lambda should be some kind of method?

Comment: I mean if this is going to be used more than once, a first-class utility method with the same name would be better than a hidden lambda. Everything else looks good.